# App Deployment Question: Lite Vs Paid

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I am developing a messaging app. It uses an SQLite database to store the user's registration. It also uses push notifications. Right now I am using a development push notification certificate.

My client now wants a "Lite" version to be built, and I am not sure how to go about it. I have read several articles on Stack Overflow and elsewhere. I am confused by all the versions I have read online.

Can anybody suggest to me what to do, specific to my situation? I don't want to lose the registration data in the database while updating from Lite to Paid version.

One more question: when someone downloads a paid version of an app, will it install as a different app or will it overwrite the existing Lite version? I am guessing it depends whether you are using a separate app ID or the same one, but I am not sure.

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your first question, what I do is just create a second target in my Xcode project. One for the Lite version and one for the paid version. Then I create a preprocessor macro for the Lite version in the Xcode build settings for the Lite target. Usually I just do `LITE=1`. Then in the code when I want to do something different for the Lite version, you can just do

```
#ifdef LITE
    //lite version
#else
    //paid version
#endif
```

And for your second question, the paid version will not overwrite the Lite version. It will be installed as a different app.

EDIT: You should consider having just one free version and providing the "paid" features via an In-App purchase. This would allow the user's preferences to migrate over from the Lite to paid version since it would actually be the same app.

Comment: In-App Purchase is also better since apple sometimes deny putting lite versions in the store. They will deny it for sure if it contains the word "lite" or "demo" anywhere in the app .)

Comment: @Bastian you're actually allowed to have Lite versions of your app in the store (I have one). You just can't advertise the full version from within the Lite version.